# Cocoapod's 'pod install' begets odd behavior with Prefix Header

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I am using `Cocoapods` in my project and have been using it for several months now.

I just added a library to my project and ran `pod install` and now my the PCH file isn't being recognized. I tried deleting and re-creating a new PCH and linking it back to my project, but to no effect.

I did notice something odd:

[image: WTH?]

Why the heck is it installing something that was supposedly already installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that odd behavior in my project was with a specific pod that was working before but is no longer working. The author must have funked up the latest version, thus causing a slew of errors in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a lot of configuration going on CocoaPods shouldn't affect your project's PCH file. Make sure you have these options setup in your Xcode project to link the file correctly.

[image: pch options]